# How to redirect to another page if user gets to a specific URL in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, redirect, next.js

I don't have "/" (index) page and i want to redirect to another page if the user gets to that page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution is to configure the redirect in the `next.config.js` file.

```
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
    async redirects() {
        return [
            {
                source: "/",
                destination: "/clients",
                permanent: true
            }
        ];
    }
};
```

Feel free to check the [redirects documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects) for more details.

Comment: I totally forgot about this solution, nice one, thanks!