# How to return different page when visiting the root of the website?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have a dynamic route at the root of my pages folder in Next; like so `src/pages/[page].js`

This works great for anything that actually has a slug for example `example.com/my-page` will return the correct data for `my-page`.

I want to be able to access a slug named `homepage` when you're visiting the root of the website. So visiting `example.com` would actually return the page `homepage`.

How can this be done? Here's a stripped back version of my component:

```
import React from "react";
import { fetchAPI } from "../lib/api";

const Page = () => <p>Content...</p>;

export default Page;

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const pages = await fetchAPI("/pages");
  return {
    paths: pages.map((page) => ({
      params: {
        page: page.slug,
      },
    })),
    fallback: false,
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const pages = await fetchAPI(`/pages?slug=${params.page}`);
  return {
    props: { page: pages[0] },
    revalidate: 1,
  };
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to redirect to another page if user gets to a specific URL in Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65471789/1870780)? You can also use [`rewrites`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites) instead if you don't want a redirect to occur.

Comment: @juliomalves I want the user to stay on the `/` root, but simply show the `/homepage` slug content (`example.com/homepage` would be kind of weird)

Comment: Using `rewrites` allows you to do that. You'll stay on `/` but see the `/homepage` page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure [`rewrites`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites) in the `next.config.js` file to map the `/` path to the `/homepage` destination path.

```js
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
    async rewrites() {
        return [
            {
                source: '/',
                destination: '/homepage'
            }
        ];
    }
};
```

This will not change the visible URL (`/`) in the address bar.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I misunderstood your original comment thinking it would `redirect` not `rewrite` (the clue was in the name I guess).

For anyone reading this, it's worth mentioning you need to restart Next if you're adding a new `next.config.js` file.

Answer (score 1):

In `getStaticProps`, your `params.page` will be undefined on your home page because you're using a dynamic route there, so you just need to handle that case:

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const pageSlug = params.page ?? "homepage"
  const pages = await fetchAPI(`/pages?slug=${pageSlug}`);
  return {
    props: { page: pages[0] },
    revalidate: 1,
  };
}
```

##### Update To Redirect 404 Pages to Homepage

OP - in your comment below, you said "*...but if a user visited something like example.com/asdopmsaiond wouldn't it also show the homepage in this case instead of a 404*". While my code above will give you the homepage slug when a user visits the home page, it seems you also want to display the home page when a user visits any page that doesn't truly exist. There are generally three ways to go about this:

###### Redirect to the home page on 404 (Preferred)

You can redirect the user to the home page if no page is found by checking your `pages` variable - if it doesn't have a valid `pages[0]` value, you'll know (assuming your api is set up well) that no page was found and you can then redirect to the home page:

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const pageSlug = params.page ?? "homepage"
  const pages = await fetchAPI(`/pages?slug=${pageSlug}`);
  if(!pages || !pages.length > 0) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: '/',
        permanent: false,
      },
    }
  }
  return {
    props: { page: pages[0] },
    revalidate: 1,
  };
}
```

I say that this is "preferred" because it will not result in SEO duplicate content penalties like the last option would, and doesn't result in any additional processing or api calls.

###### Redirect with 404.js (or 404.tsx)

You can create a 404.js (or 404.tsx) file which Next uses when it needs to display a 404 page. This file also takes `getStaticProps` which you can use to just redirect to the home page:

```
// 404.js
export default function FourOhFourPage() {
  return null
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  return {
    redirect: {
      destination: '/',
      permanent: false,
    },
  };
}
```

###### Display the home page on any 404 url

You can also resubmit your api call with the `homepage` slug if no `pages` are found in your api call, and then display that `homepage` content. This would result in a second api call and you'd want to include a canonical url to your home page so you don't get hit with duplicate content penalties for SEO:

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const pageSlug = params.page ?? "homepage"
  // Changed `pages` from `const` to `let` so we can modify it
  // if we don't get the desired result from the api call
  let pages = await fetchAPI(`/pages?slug=${pageSlug}`);
  if(!pages || !pages.length > 0) {
    pages = await fetchAPI(`/pages?slug=homepage`);
  }
  return {
    props: { page: pages[0] },
    revalidate: 1,
  };
}
```

Comment: I'll try this out, but if a user visited something like `example.com/asdopmsaiond` wouldn't it also show the homepage in this case instead of a 404?

Comment: @ChrishD I updated my answer with some additional ways to handle your 404 cases.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Another user posted a slightly more elegant solution using `rewrites` which seemed to do the trick without much configuration, but this seems like a great solution too.